# expat.redist in nuget deploys the wrong DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, nuget, expat-parser

I have added the Nuget/Coapp package for Expat (https://github.com/coapp-packages/expat) to my Visual C++ 2012 project. The project is using the Unicode charset and I finally found where I configure the Expat build rules (Project properties > "Configuration Properties" > "Referenced Packages" > "expat"). I have set the "UTFwidth" property there to "utf16". This is working, ie `XML_Char` becomes `wchar_t` during compilation. However, it seems that the redistributable package which contains the DLLs is not affected by this setting, because it copies "libexpat.dll" instead of "libexpatw.dll" to the output directory. If I manually copy the correct DLL, my programme is running as expected.

How do I fix the build process to copy the right version of the DLL?

Comment: I have a similar problem with the nuget packages of zlib and libpng in visual studio 2013. They don't link because the targets are missing.